# Instagram API, login with two-factor authentication enabled

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I have an Android application, which is using the Instagram API to get users' recent images. I use

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

The problem: some users have 2F authentication enabled, so this API does not work and those users cannot login. Unfortunately, I did not find any doc on Instagram on how to deal with it and there is no way to contact Instagram for support.

I need help finding a way login with 2F enabled.